# final class vs non final compiler optimizations

Tags: scala

Is there any advantage for compiler from final classes? Does it do any optimizations when class is final vs non-final?
I see a lot of classes declared final in libraries code, so just wonder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's get the most important thing out of the way first: making a class `final` or not is *primarily* a modeling decision made by the programmer. `final` and non-`final` classes have differing semantics, so it is simply not possible to apply `final` purely for performance reasons.

In particular, *only* if a class is `final` can you guarantee its properties and invariants. If the class is *not* `final`, a subclass could come along and override methods in such a way as to break (some of) the properties and invariants.

The most obvious example is if you want to write an immutable type: if a subclass can simply override your methods with mutable versions, then there is no guarantee that your type will be immutable, ergo, if you want your type be immutable, it *must* be `final`.

Since the Scala standard library, the Scala Platform, and the wider Scala ecosystem and community has a lot of immutable types, there are also going to be a lot of `final` classes.

So, to repeat: making a class `final` is a *semantic* decision, it has nothing to do with optimization. You typically don't have a choice of making your class `final` or not, it either *must* be `final` to preserve its invariants, or it is designed to be a base class, in which case, it *can't* be `final`.

As to your question about compiler optimizations: yes, there is a benefit to the compiler. It is actually not so much about `final` classes, but about `final` methods. There are some optimizations for which the compiler must prove that a method cannot be overridden at this point. In general, this is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, but for `final` methods, this is trivially true. So, for example, you can always inline calls to `final` methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Scala Reference manual](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The **final** modifier applies to class member definitions and to class
>   definitions. A final class member definition may not be overridden in
>   subclasses. A final class may not be inherited by a template. final is
>   redundant for object definitions. Members of final classes or objects
>   are implicitly also final, so the final modifier is generally
>   redundant for them, too. Note, however, that constant value
>   definitions (§4.1) do require an explicit final modifier, even if they
>   are defined in a final class or object. final may not be applied to
>   incomplete members, and it may not be combined in one modifier list
>   with sealed.

For the compiler there is no significant improvement of performance or advantage, is just a part of language constraint.